# TortoiseSVN : Which should come first, updating or committing?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've already tried using tortoise git. I've used it for months and my usual routine when I made some changes in my local is, commit, pull and push.
That seems except for the occasional issue with HEAD tags in the files.

Now, in my current job, I use tortoiseSVN. And the difference if the 2 is obvious, in **SVN update is equivalent to pull of GIT**. and so far I couldn't find **push** . Or maybe it is because I haven't committed anything yet.

Now my biggest worry is I need to push something in the repo. And the last time I update/pull was 2 weeks ago.

My question is, since that's the case, what should I do first, update, commit then push? Or commit, update then push?

I've read here [SVN Update, What happens to a local file with uncommitted changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790410/svn-update-what-happens-to-a-local-file-with-uncommitted-changes) that if you update with uncommitted changes, *It will merge HEAD with your local copy. If the changes collide - you get a nice conflict.* So if I commit first then update, will I be able to avoid "that" conflict? And by the way, where is SVN's command that is equivalent to push? I've read some articles about it but I don't understand it.

Comment: Wait a minute...are you using TortoiseSVN or a Git plugin or some sort?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi. No, I'm not using plugin.

Comment: SVN commit automatically does a "push" because you're committing directly to the server.

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html - If you try to commit a file that's already changed on the server, you get a "File is out of date" error.

Answer (score 3):

Before committing your changes into repository you **must** update in order to have latest changes merged (and possible conflicts - resolved *before* commit).

No, you can't commit in order to avoid conflicted changes - SVN will not allow you to commit objects, which was already changed by another person

Answer (score 1):

It could work both ways because as @melpomene said "committing a file that's already changed on the server gives a "File is out of date" error." and it will ask you to take an update. So once you take update you will be able to commit it.

So conclusion is that if you want to quickly update & commit then directly commit the changes so that if there is a server change you will get an update suggestion from SVN and in best case if server file hasn't changed you won't get it & commit will be successfull.

If you know that server file has changed or you want be fail-safe then first take an update & then commit the changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I update first, isnt it going to overwrite whatever it is that i've already worked on?

Comment: No it won't overwrite it, It will give you possible conflicts error and then will ask you to resolve it.